# How to speed up Animation Preview

Tags: animation

There are a lot of similar questions but I still can't find a simple answer.
I have my Run Cycle animation with 50 frames. But when I play it, it is slow for running. I want to speed it up without scaling and moving keyframes closer. I can put the Frame Rate on 120 or 240 but I still can't get it because my maximum is 70 fps. Also, Time Remapping isn't handy to me because when I change it from 100 to 25 for example, it plays 25 frames only.
Is there some faster way instead of scaling and moving keyframes closer and so on?

Comment: Have you tried a render in Solid or Material Previsew mode (View > Viewport Render Animation)? You can also drop some frames (Timeline window > Playback > Sync > Frame Dropping) but of course it will drop frames  ;)  Cycles is very slow to calculate so you can't have real time render

Comment: Actually it is already in Solid View mode, without materials.. Maybe simplifying it could help, but then I would lost details on mesh needed for precise preview :/

Comment: I would increase frames per second (double) and render every second frame.

Answer (score 1):

what u can do is.
Go to the **TIME REMAPPING** in PROPERTIES PANEL and increase the **NEW VALUE**
[image: TIME REMAPPING]

Comment: Actually I decrease it so it becomes faster, but then animation cycles only with 25 frames for example if I put it at 25 and my animation is 50 frames. Then I need to add more keyframes by duplicating those old one and then manually change all of them later on and by that I got more unnecessary work.